# How to deserialize different object properties into a common class with Moshi?

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, moshi

I started writing the Java library [Brockman](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Brockman) to parse a JSON response similar to [this example](https://gist.github.com/MaZderMind/d5737ab867ade7888cb4) using [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi). However, the format requires to generalize a bit for the `stream` objects.

The video stream excerpt:

```
{
    "slug": "hd-native",
    "display": "Saal 1 FullHD Video",
    "type": "video",
    "isTranslated": false,
    "videoSize": [
        1920,
        1080
    ],
    "urls": {
        "webm": {
            "display": "WebM",
            "tech": "1920x1080, VP8+Vorbis in WebM, 2.8 MBit/s",
            "url": "http://example.com/s1_native_hd.webm"
        },
        "hls": {
            "display": "HLS",
            "tech": "1920x1080, h264+AAC im MPEG-TS-Container via HTTP",
            "url": "http://example.com/hls/s1_native_hd.m3u8"
        }
    }
}
```

The audio stream excerpt:

```
{
    "slug": "audio-native",
    "display": "Saal 1 Audio",
    "type": "audio",
    "isTranslated": false,
    "videoSize": null,
    "urls": {
        "mp3": {
            "display": "MP3",
            "tech": "MP3-Audio, 96 kBit/s",
            "url": "http://example.com/s1_native.mp3"
        },
        "opus": {
            "display": "Opus",
            "tech": "Opus-Audio, 64 kBit/s",
            "url": "http://example.com/s1_native.opus"
        }
    }
}
```

The content of the `urls = {}` object differs dependent on whether the `stream` `type` is `video` or `audio` as one can see from the examples above.

Currently, there are only the models [`Mp3`](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Brockman/blob/761a16af5d0aba422c13cf38639c38c9c3f80bfb/src/main/java/info/metadude/java/library/brockman/models/Mp3.java) and [`Opus`](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Brockman/blob/761a16af5d0aba422c13cf38639c38c9c3f80bfb/src/main/java/info/metadude/java/library/brockman/models/Opus.java) which are identical by their properties. I would like to substitute them with a `Format` class which could also act as a replacement for the missing `Webm` and `Hls` classes. How can I actually map the different fields of the `Urls` object into the `Format` class?

```
public class Format {

    public final String display;
    public final String tech;
    public final String url;

    public Format(String display, String tech, String url) {
        this.display = display;
        this.tech = tech;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

I could imagine that the [`Stream` class](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Brockman/blob/761a16af5d0aba422c13cf38639c38c9c3f80bfb/src/main/java/info/metadude/java/library/brockman/models/Stream.java) would look something like this:

```
public class Stream {

    public final String display;
    public final boolean isTranslated;
    public final String slug;
    public final String type;
    public final VideoSize videoSize;
    public final List<Format> urls; // How to map into List<Format>?

// ...
```

Comment: Why must you use Moshi?  Isn't GSON converter enough.  Then you could use `@SerializedName("mp3")` or similar for the Format class

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Please watch [A few Ok libraries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvyScM_S88c) to learn about the advantages of Moshi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following:

```
public class StreamAdapter {

    @ToJson
    public String toJson(Stream stream) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented.");
    }

    @FromJson
    public Stream fromJson(StreamJson streamJson) throws Exception {
        String slug = streamJson.slug;
        String display = streamJson.display;
        boolean isTranslated = streamJson.isTranslated;
        Stream.TYPE type = streamJson.type;
        VideoSize videoSize = streamJson.videoSize;
        Map<String, Object> urlsJson = streamJson.urls;
        List<Url> urls = getUrls(urlsJson);
        return new Stream(display, isTranslated, slug, type, videoSize, urls);
    }

    private List<Url> getUrls(Map<String, Object> urlsJson) {
        Set<String> urlTypes = urlsJson.keySet();
        List<Url> urls = new ArrayList<Url>(urlTypes.size());
        for (String urlType : urlTypes) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, String> urlProperties = (Map<String, String>) urlsJson.get(urlType);
            urls.add(getUrl(urlType, urlProperties));
        }
        return urls;
    }

    private Url getUrl(String urlType, Map<String, String> properties) {
        Url.TYPE type = new UrlTypeAdapter().fromJson(urlType);
        String display = properties.get("display");
        String tech = properties.get("tech");
        String url = properties.get("url");
        return new Url(type, display, tech, url);
    }

    private static final class StreamJson {
        String slug;
        String display;
        boolean isTranslated;
        Stream.TYPE type;
        VideoSize videoSize;
        Map<String, Object> urls;
    }

}
```

Note that I use an `Url` class now instead of the `Format` class mentioned in the question. Please find more details [here](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Brockman). If you have ideas on how to improve this you are welcome to **comment here** or **create an issue/pull request** on the repository.

Comment: I referenced your solution in a Moshi feature request: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/133

Comment: Where to use this `StreamAdapter`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You have to [add the adapter to Moshi](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Brockman/blob/53e81d4f5eaa9e48b2e89171ef9177b28c8dea17/src/main/java/info/metadude/java/library/brockman/ApiModule.java#L30).

Comment: @JJD  Seems like a lot of boilerplate code.  Is it really necessary to write this adapter and add to Moshi?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Feel free to suggest a smarter solution. I was under time pressure when I worked on the project. At least it work for me.